# Tensorflow - I don't get the right shapes - `ValueError: Shapes (9, 1) and (8, 9) are incompatible`

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, data, preprocessing, categorical-encoding

I want to train a Sequential Neural Net (NN) with Tensorflow.

```
bidding_nn = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'),
#tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=9, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'),
])
```

and

```
adam = Adam(lr=0.02, decay=0.01)
bidding_nn.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

bidding_nn.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)
```

It should tell me probabilities for the 9 categories I have.

So as input for the NN, I have 8 npArrays of lengths 32 (one-hot encoded) and as output 1 npArray of lengths 9 (one-hot encoded).

```
(Pdb) train_dataset
<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((8, 32), (9,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
```

However, at `bidding_nn.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)` I get the error message

```
    ValueError: Shapes (9, 1) and (8, 9) are incompatible
```

++++++++++++++++++++++
Answer to the problem, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66350991/12368039

Comment: What line of code did you run to get the `ValueError` you received?

Comment: when I call `.fit()` in here `bidding_nn.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)`

Comment: I got an answer that perfectly fit the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66350991/12368039

Comment: Good to hear, please also add the exact answer that solved your problem for other users who may be getting the same error.